# Use form elements in codeigniter way

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I change the following html elements in codeigniter way?

```
<select id="gender" name ="gender">
        <option value="val_male" selected="Male">male</option>
        <option value="val_female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <input id="id_ok" type="button" value="OK" class="btn btn-primary v-align">
```

I tried the following..But it is incorrect.
Any help?

```
<?php 
$options = array(
                  'val_male'    => 'Male',
                   'val_female'   => 'Female',
                );
echo form_dropdown('gender', $options, 'Male');
echo form_button('id_ok', 'OK');
?>
```

Comment: What happens then?

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect? Please state the actual problem in detail.

Comment: change  `echo form_dropdown('gender', $options, 'Male');` to `echo form_dropdown('gender', $options, 'val_male');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this like:

```
$data = array(
        'name'          => 'username',
        'id'            => 'username',
        'value'         => 'johndoe',
        'maxlength'     => '100',
        'size'          => '50',
        'style'         => 'width:50%'
);

echo form_input($data);
```

Would produce:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="johndoe" id="username" maxlength="100" size="50" style="width:50%"  />
```

[Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add key parameter (which become `value` of option element) in selected value

```
$options = array(
                  'val_male'    => 'Male',
                   'val_female'   => 'Female',
                );
echo form_dropdown('gender', $options, 'val_male');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$options = array(
              'val_male'    => 'Male',
               'val_female'   => 'Female',
            );
echo form_dropdown('gender', $options, 'val_male');
echo form_button('id_ok', 'OK');

?>
```

don't forget to load form_helper before using form methods